# MessageSource.MessageSink is null

Tags: c#, message, postsharp

This is what I have:

```
Message msg = new Message(SeverityType.Error,"xx","xx", "xx");
IMessageSink sink = MessageSource.MessageSink;
sink.Write(msg);   // NullReferenceException (sink == null)
```

While I was doing some digging online, it seems like every example is using MessageSource.MessageSink.Write(msg), and I'm confused why my code doesn't work.

Any help is appreacited.

Answer (score 0):

You should write using `Message.Write`.

Comment: I thought Message.Write would work, but I got the same error.  It's weird; I don't see anything that hasn't been assigned yet...

Comment: When do you use it? At build time (in CompileTimeValidate) or run time (in an advise)? This works only at build time, since it writes a message to the build process.

Comment: Some of my strings are (MethodBase) method.Name, so it's run time, isn't it?

Comment: You should know whether you are at build time or at runtime. Messages can be written only from methods CompileTimeInitialize or CompileTimeValidate.